# Upgrade TFS 2005 to TFS 2010

Tags: team-foundation-server

Anyone has any recommendations, articles, manuals or instructions for upgrading TFS 2005 to TFS 2010? Interested walkthroughs, articles describing possible problems. I would be grateful for any information.

Add: I found this shot instruction:

```
Backup your databases!
If you are using SQL 2005, upgrade to SQL 2008 or SQL 2008 R2
If you are using SharePoint 2.0 and want to continue using SharePoint, upgrade to 3.0
Restore your TFS databases to your SQL instance
Install TFS 2010
After Install finishes but before running the Upgrade Wizard, apply the upgrade hotfix linked above
Run the Upgrade Wizard and point to your TFS databases
```

What can be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a walkthrough for upgrade to TFS2010. You can upgrade from TFS2005, no problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff803410.aspx

Make sure you upgrade SQL Server to SQL Server 2008 (or higher) and SharePoint to WSS 3.0 (or higher) before you start the upgrade. If you don't care about SharePoint, you can always skip it. You have to have SQL Server. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what you wrote is true, but I have long been upgraded TFS.

Comment: My bad. I hadn't noticed the date. Thanks for the up vote, sorry it wasn't more helpful~